# Oracle exception ::getMessage() causing debug assertion

Tags: c++, oracle

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise with Oracle 12.1.0. Here's the code causing assertion:

```
try
{
    // ..
}catch(oracle::occi::SQLException &e)
{
    std::cout << "Error code: " << e.getErrorCode() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Error message: " << e.getMessage() << std::endl;   // Most likely here 
}
```

I'm assuming it has something to do with std::string being allocated by dll and deallocated by application but I'm not sure. Also I got no idea on how to fix it.

Edit 1: "catch by value" to "catch by reference"

Edit 2: With Visual Studio 2013(v120) platform toolset I don't get the assertion. With Visual Studio 2015(v140) platform toolset I get it even though code, library and project settings are same.

Comment: You should really be `catch`ing exceptions by reference, not by value. `oracle::occi::SQLException& e`

Comment: Which debug assertion ?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks. Modified accordingly.

Comment: @Christophe __acrt_first_block == header

Comment: @AcarX *Also I got no idea on how to fix it.*  -- You need to state if that exception object was created by a DLL or within your executable.  If it was generated by the DLL, then any solution may be very painful due to passing objects such as `std::string` across DLL boundaries.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie How do I check if it was created by DLL or application? I'm assuming it was created by DLL. I had no issue with Visual Studio 2013 using same code/library/dll.

Comment: The issue is that the `std::string` used by the Oracle DLL may be incompatible (different internals) than the `std::string` used by Visual Studio 2015.  If so, then you need to get a version of the DLL compatible with VS 2015.  The other thing that can cause issues is if you built your application using settings that changes internally the `std::string` class that makes it incompatible with the `std::string` from Oracle.  There are other issues, but these are the drawbacks of using DLL's that use types like `std::string` to interface with.

Comment: I haven't changed std::string implementation and same code works in visual studio 2013 so I'll assume that standard std::string in visual studio 2015 is incompitable with my oracle library. I'm using the most recent version of OCCI library so I guess there's nothing I can do..

Comment: It seems Oracle is a bit slow adding support for new versions of the MS Visual studio compilers. They're now up to VS2013: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NTCLI/pre_install.htm#NTCLI1252